# Running a controller with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

```
.controller('randomImageController', function($scope, $http, Image) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    Image.random()
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.image = data[0];
        $scope.loading = false;
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

This loads when calling the url /random. It calls my API and returns a random DB row from a table.

My aim now is to have a button in that template that will call that function again and display another random image.

```
<section class="random-image">
    <img src="/images/{{ image.name }}">
    <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="randomImage();">Load New</button>
</section>
```

If I change my controller to look like this:

```
.controller('randomImageController', function($scope, $http, Image) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    Image.random()
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.image = data[0];
        $scope.loading = false;
        console.log(data);
    });
    $scope.randomImage = function() {
        console.log('reload');
    };
});
```

The reload is shown in the console, but I cant figure out how to 'recall' as it were that controller?

Comment: this doesn't really make sense.  why is the logic in the constructor of the controller instead of inside a reusable function?

Comment: You don't "call a controller". You call a function inside the controller. Put the code you want to call inside `$scope.randomImage()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the reusable code into a function, and call that function if necessary on controller load.

```js
.controller('randomImageController', function($scope, $http, Image) {

  $scope.randomImage = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    Image.random()
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.image = data[0];
        $scope.loading = false;
        console.log(data);
      });
  };

  $scope.randomImage();
});
```

In this way, you aren't "reloading the controller", rather you are re-executing the reusable code.